# select box work as toggle button in internet explorere while in other browser its working perfect

Tags: html, wordpress

I am working in wordpress.I have created one dropdown.Its working fine in Chrome and Mozilla but it's not working in Internet Explorer.

My website [link](http://www.kitchendeli.com/front/).

You can check dropdown on **where do you want?** tab under **order now**.

Its a browser issue so how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What code you've added? how does it look? which version of browser you are taking about? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: version is Internet Explorer 10